# Подключение к postgresql через sqlalchemy. Непонятный момент

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

По тренировочному примеру осваиваю FastApi. Создал модели данных в models.py.
Далее в терминале

```
alembic init migrations
```

в главной папке появился файл alembic.ini

не пойму эту строчку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а именно возникают следующие вопросы.

1. Что делает эта переменная sqlalchemy.url ? Видимо не такой ловкач чтобы найти в документации это
2. Что делают эти знаки %s ? Если это форматирование строк с помощью оператора %, то должен быть формат файла .py а тут .ini , не понятно что делает в ini файле такой оператор.
3. Тот же вопрос что и выше, но с @. Что он делает в .ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта переменная задает url подключения к базе данных в виде переменных подстановки. Вероятнее всего, сами значения переменных берутся из файла `env.py`, чтобы в конечном итоге у вас была строка подключения к базе виде

```
postgresql://user:password@server/dbname
```

Это не оператор, это обычный шаблон подстановки, и он вполне себе может находится в .ini-файле.

- `%(NAME)s` - говорит о том, что здесь должна быть переменная окружения строкового типа с именем NAME
- `@` - стандартный разделитель пользовательских данных и uri в url.

Comment: Спасибо большое) А переменные берутся в тестовом примере из файла вот с таким названием .env